# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client NodeJS Redirect

Tags: node.js, email, redirect

I have some IF/Else stataments, in IF statament I could make an redirect, but in else statament I couldn't.
Code that I use:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
router.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/html/index.html'));
    var email = req.query.email;

    conn.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [email], function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err;
        var resultLength = result.length;
        if (email != null && resultLength == 0) {
            conn.query('INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)', [email], function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('1 record inserted')
                res.write('<p>You are now subscribed to our newsletter!</p>');
            })
            res.redirect('/succes')
        }else{
            console.log("You are already subscribed to our newsletter!")
            res.redirect('/error')
        }


    })


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send ONE and only one response to a given request.  When you do:

```
res.sendFile(...)
```

that sends a response to the incoming request.  Attempting to send ANY other request will cause the error about "cannot send headers after they are already sent".

Yet, in your code, you then try to do both `res.write(...)` and `res.redirect(...)`.  You simply can't do that.  You get to send one and only one response to a given incoming request.  You already sent one with `res.sendFile(...)`.

Then, even further, you can't do a `res.write(...)`, then followed by `res.redirect(...)`.  Doing a `res.write(...)` means that the http library has to send the headers so that it can now start sending the body.  So, this forces the headers to get sent.  But, now when you do a `res.redirect(...)`, you're telling the Express library that you want to set a 302 status code and you want to set the `Location` header.  Hmmm, but the status code has already been sent and the headers have already been sent, forced out by the `res.write(...)`.  So, at this point, `res.redirect(...)` cannot do its job.

It's unclear what this code is supposed to do.  You're either serving `index.html` or you're doing something else that redirects to a different URL.  The same route can't do both of those operations.  For a route like this, you either send an HTML response OR you redirect to another URL.  Pick one.

---

Here's one possible solution that contains only `res.redirect()`:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    const email = req.query.email;
    if (!email) {
        console.log("req.query.email not present");
        res.redirect('/error')
        return;
    }

    conn.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [email], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/error')
            return;
        }
        const resultLength = result.length;
        if (resultLength == 0) {
            conn.query('INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)', [email], function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect('/error')
                    return;
                }
                console.log('1 record inserted')
                res.redirect('/succes');
                return;
            })
        } else {
            console.log("You are already subscribed to our newsletter!")
            res.redirect('/error')
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tryed all of these ( res.redirect, res.write, res.sendFile ) and none of them worked. Can you please tell me what I need to use to redirect, please?

Comment: @DanielDinca -  `res.redirect()` will work just fine as long as you make NO OTHER call that sends a response in the same request handler.  Use `res.redirect()` all by itself.  No `res.write()`, no `res.sendFile()`.  It's explained thoroughly in my answer.  Use only one of these.

Comment: @DanielDinca - See the possible solution I added to my answer.

Comment: And now with this code that worked, I finally understand what do you mean in first answer !